# Events Summary Report

Tags: civireport

I am trying to run a report of all Events with a start date in the current week, which would show title, start date, and ideally number of participants registered.  The nearest I can get is the Income Count Summary Report, but this does not seem to pick up the number of participants, even though the field is selected in Columns.  Also, there appears to be no tab for sorting, so the events are sorted in a random order, when date order would be useful.  Is there another option I could try for this report?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your version of CiviCRM you can probably get what you need with SearchKit:

- search for events with event participants
- where event start date in 'this week'
- add columns to results to include event name, date, participant id (and any other column you may want/need)
- group by event id
- set field transformations to count on 'participant id'

[image]